# Display of Android fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to get a fragment to display in Android. When I execute the code to go to the correct fragment, all I see is the toast. The fragment_detail does not appear. Does anyone have any idea what's wrong with this code?
From the calling class:

```
            final FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();
            ft.replace( R.id.pager, df, "DetailFragment" ).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).commit();
```

From the called class:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Blah de Blah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        return rootView;
    }
```

The layout for fragment_detail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Large Text"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: in `ft.replace( R.id.pager, ddf, "DetailFragment" )` ddf or df?

Comment: Sorry, typo has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be an XML issue, try changing the below:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" /> />
```

Should be:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected that issue, however, I am still having the same problem. Any ideas?